# Is this a safe way of inserting an element into a C array?

Tags: arrays, c

I am currently learning data structures in C, and I came across this piece of code from tutorialspoint where they insert an element into an array as shown in the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int linearArray[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 8};
  int itemToInsert = 314159265;
  int indexToInsert = 3;
  int numElements = 5;
  int i = 0, j = numElements;

  printf("The elements in the original array are: \n");

  for(i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
    printf("Index %d: %d \n", i, linearArray[i]);
  }

  numElements += 1;

  while(j >= indexToInsert) {
    linearArray[j + 1] = linearArray[j];
    j -= 1;
  }

  linearArray[indexToInsert] = itemToInsert;

  printf("The elements in the modified array are: \n");

  for(i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
    printf("Index %d: %d \n", i, linearArray[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

As far as I understand, if there is no array size declared in the brackets when initializing the array, it is initialized with a size based on the number of elements. Would it be safe to keep on adding elements into an array the way they do so, or would it use memory which it is not supposed to an potentially corrupt data on my hard drive?

Comment: You're not missing anything - the code is just utterly broken.  The perils of getting random code from online.

Comment: @lurence That is just an awful code.:)

Comment: @NateEldredge I see, thank you for confirming my suspicion. Would there be any proper way to insert elements into an array, or would I be better off using something such as a linked list?

Comment: "Inserting an element into an array" is kind of a flawed term. Generally inserting into an array is not possible, since arrays have a fixed size that can't be changed at run-time. However, if you have an array of X elements, where only Y elements are "used" (with Y < X) then you could easily add new values after the current Y. Or if you want to add elements in the middle, then you need to shift (copy) elements after the insertion point toward the end of the array.

Comment: You can't enlarge the size of a static or auto array.  If it was dynamically allocated, you can `realloc` it, and then do something like what this code does, shifting all later elements.  But if the array is of any size or needs frequent inserts, you probably do want a linked list or other structure.

Comment: @lurence I suspect that the tutorial is written by a senior programmer.:)

Comment: Oh, it has a bonus off-by-one bug where the `while(j >= indexToInsert)` shifts an extra element of the array that isn't even there.